# How to make html file from textarea content

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a html file from the contents fetched from the textarea.

I want to know, how to save the html file and how will I get this html file in my location from the content shown below

```
'<textarea id="Textarea"><html><head></head><body>Hai</body></html></textarea>`
```

Comment: @what do you mean "save"? You can upload the html snippet to your server, but it is impossible to save it in the local file system.

Comment: It is possible to save the file in the local system with the help of the scripts. How do you say that it is impossible

Comment: @Rajesh - where you want save file with content from textarea: on client or on server?

Answer (score 3):

When you submit the text area content, the server side code should create file with these contents and save it at a location which is accessible to the browser via some URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to a file using JavaScript you can't. You can pass `document.getElementById('Textarea').innerHTML` to a webservice that will save it's output to a file...

Comment: Why can't you write a file using javascripts? There are ways to write files using javascript. Before posting the answer please check and post what you are posting. And don't post just like that.

Comment: Because that's how the language was implemented. It's for security reasons. JavaScript itself doesn't allow File IO. You have to use Third party plug-ins or Node.JS for file IO.

Answer (score 0):

The following did the magic for me:
`$message = str_replace('&lt;','<',$message); $message = str_replace('&gt;','>',$message);`